# WPF CrystalReport unknown field

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I have this dialog where I can print diffent kind of Crysal Reports

[image]

But when I choose the Radio buttons Med Læsertal and Med Post nr I get this error

[image]

I cannot figure out why the field name is unknown because the field does exist on the table.

Comment: I'd expect a parameter to be a field. Why's there a dot there?

Comment: @Andy what dot?

Comment: Both of the things on each side of that = have a full stop in them.